# Problems With Resetting Password - Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, erb

I'm having problems when resetting a password using Devise.

When I click on 'Send me reset password instructions', I get:

```
ArgumentError at /users/password
Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

It says that the problem is in `/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb` on line 5.

On line 5 in that file there is:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @resource.reset_password_token) %></p>
```

I have no idea how to setup a mailer in Rails although I have tried to. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, you need to set up default url options for the mailer in each
environment. Here is the configuration for "config/environments/development.rb":

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

You need to specify the host so it can be shown in the confimation email.

Comment: It's working now I have that. How do I know it Will it work in production?

Comment: You have to do the same but in "config/environments/production.rb" with the actual production host instead

Comment: Do I not have to add a mailer? How does it know what email to use?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration

Answer (score 1):

You can create a default filter like this:

```
 # application_controller.rb
    before_filter :mailer_set_url_options
```

...

```
def mailer_set_url_options
  ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = request.host_with_port
end
```